# Generic HTTP security path matcher, reference matched path in security expression

Tags: spring, spring-security, matcher

Right now, with Spring Security's `HttpSecurity`, we're able to restrict wildcard paths to specific roles/authorities:

```
.mvcMatchers(POST, "/users").hasAuthority("create:users")
.mvcMatchers(PUT, "/users/{id}").hasAuthority("update:users")
```

is there an easy way to do:

```
.mvcMatchers(POST, "/{whateverGoesHere}").hasAuthority("create:${whateverGoesHere}")
.mvcMatchers(PUT, "/{whateverGoesHere}/{id}").hasAuthority("update:${whateverGoesHere}")
```

?

It doesn't have to be a solution using the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` API specifically, I'm just looking for an easy way to generify authorization rules for multiple REST entities at once.

Comment: You could implement it by yourself. Both are just `String` values. Something like `.mvcMatchers(POST, "/"+whateverGoesHere).hasAuthority("create:"+whateverGoesHere)`. You have to know `whateverGoesHere`, because you have to add it to your users anyway.

Comment: @dur I'm afraid you missed the point. I want new controllers to be configured by convention, so that when I create `@RepositoryRestResource(path = "products")` for instance, the `/products` REST resource is already automatically secured, without ever having to think about updating the security config.

Comment: I didn't miss the point. As I wrote, you have to know the paths anyway, because you need to add it to your users as roles/authorities. If you do it, for example in your database, you can read the path from your database and create the ant matchers accordently.

Comment: It makes no sense to add only new controllers, which no user could ever access. You also have to add roles to your users.

Comment: @dur Adding roles to users is a separate matter. I would like a configuration that I could then reuse across multiple Spring components that, when a Rest resource is registered (e.g. `projects`), will automatically require a user trying to request `PUT /users/{id}` to have the `update:projects` permission, without ever having to write `.mvcMatchers(PUT, "/users/{id}").hasAuthority("update:users")` explicitly, anywhere. I then know I need to add `update:users` to my user for them to be able to access `PUT /users/{id}` precisely because this is the convention my components use out of the box.

Comment: And I don't want to add the paths to the DB or anywhere else, quite the opposite - I don't want a developer of a new API resource to have to think about setting up authorization rules for the new endpoint. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously a more advanced scenario, to say the least. However, improvements in Spring Security 5.5 have introduced the new `AuthorizationManager` interface and the `http.authorizeHttpRequests()` method for configuring authorization rules that utilize it. See [The AuthorizationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#_the_authorizationmanager) in the reference docs for more info. It is extremely powerful! I believe this is probably the best option for your use case.

There are numerous implementations available in Spring Security that can be used to build composite and/or delegating implementations. Here's an example that uses your convention:

```java
public final class ResourceAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> {

    private final String action;

    public ResourceAuthorizationManager(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, RequestAuthorizationContext context) {
        AuthorizationManager<RequestAuthorizationContext> delegate =
            AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority(createAuthority(context));
        return delegate.check(authentication, context);
    }

    private String createAuthority(RequestAuthorizationContext context) {
        String resource = context.getVariables().get("resource");
        return String.format("%s:%s", this.action, resource);
    }

}
```

The `action` can be `create`, `read`, `update`, `delete` or anything you like as part of your authority string. This implementation relies on URI variables provided through the `RequestAuthorizationContext`. As it happens, there's an existing implementation (`RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager`) that handles that scenario. It is actually the one handling `.mvcMatchers()` authorization rules in the Spring Security DSL. Here's an example that uses it to delegate to the convention-based `AuthorizationManager` above:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) -> authorizeHttpRequests
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/{resource}").access(new ResourceAuthorizationManager("create"))
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/{resource}/{id}").access(new ResourceAuthorizationManager("update"))
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: This looks even easier than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Kudos to Josh and the amazing contributors of Spring Security who made this (easily) possible!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should not have hidden behavior in your code. If a developer wants to add a new endpoint and wants to have it require some authority, it should be done intentionally. Otherwise, it could become a debugging nightmare if the dev intends to add an open endpoint and wonders why it is secured.

But you could add a default behavior for all endpoints that you did not specify. That behavior could be to deny access. That way, every developer has to add some kind of access granting entry. That would guarantee that it is not forgotten, but it is still intentionally done.

```java
...
.mvcMatchers(POST, "/users").hasAuthority("create:users")
.mvcMatchers(PUT, "/users/{id}").hasAuthority("update:users")
.anyRequest().denyAll()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I believe I stated my requirements quite clearly. Also, it want constitute a 'debugging nightmare' if this convention is clearly communicated to developers. It's not very different from, say, Spring Data Rest making `/products` the default URL for a resource named `Product`, or JPA making `product` the default table name for the same entity. And it's not confusing, because certain conventions are followed in those scenarios that are clearly stated in their respective docs.

Comment: Also, I believe 'it could become a debugging nightmare if the dev intends to add an open endpoint and wonders why it is secured' is a direct contradiction of 'But you could add a default behavior for all endpoints that you did not specify. That behavior could be to deny access.' I believe you need to make up your mind what's supposed to be confusing: adding a new endpoint and finding it open, or adding it and finding it closed? IMHO neither is obvious, and that's precisely why we have conventions.

Comment: It is currently not a common convention that endpoints are secured by an operation:path authority. That is why this would be unclear to new people on the team. You could have documentation that explains this convention in your project, but I believe that this does not make it more accessible. 

Also, every Spring dev should know what `.anyRequest().denyAll()` means, But if you have your code generate security config on the fly based on mapped paths, that is not clear.

Comment: If you really want to have a single point of config, why not create a custom annotation that basically adds @RequestMapping(path="/xyz",method="123") and @PostAuthorize("hasAuthority(123:xyz)" to a Controller?

Comment: 'It is currently not a common convention' - a convention is something a group of people agrees upon, and once all of those people come to an agreement, it becomes common. Is the point you're trying to make that new conventions are never established?

Comment: 'why not create a custom annotation that basically adds @RequestMapping and @PostAuthorize("hasAuthority(XYZ)" to a Controller?' Because I don't have a 'controller' in Spring Data Rest (nor do I want to have one for the sole purpose of setting up authorization rules). Thanks for what I believe is a first attempt on answering my question, but I need something that allows for authorization rules to be configured outside controllers

Comment: no, there can be new common conventions. But you are not creating them by saying that this is our convention now. There is a good reason why the default is that endpoints are not secured. And I believe that reason is to have the developer actively decide which security is needed on which endpoint. It might make sense to have some kind of simplification in place if you have a project where hundreds of similar endpoints exist. But in all other cases, the convenience of having a simpler configuration seams to be worth less than the value of having new devs understand the logic right away.

Comment: If you like, you can also implement your own MethodSecurityExpressionOperations. Not that this would make the logic more clear, but If you want this kind of solution.

You can find an article describing its use here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression

Comment: 'But you are not creating them by saying that this is our convention now' - Umm, that's precisely how conventions are created. 'But in all other cases, the convenience of having a simpler configuration seams to be worth less than the value of having new devs understand the logic right away' - you do understand that 99% of Spring Boot convention-over-configuration approach represents the exact opposite of your statement?

Comment: 'you can also implement your own MethodSecurityExpressionOperations' - thanks, and if you post another answer detailing on how to do it for my use case (specifically, how to access path variables from within the new security expression), I will accept it. I'm not debating the utility of my requirement any more, though, let me be the judge of that